# Why is the probability of $\emptyset$ equal to 0?

Tags: probability-theory

I'm wondering why is the probability of the empty set, $\emptyset$, equal to 0?

\begin{equation}
P(\emptyset) = 0.
\end{equation}
Isn't the empty set always included when you take the all the possible subsets of a set?

Comment: Intuitively, $P[\phi]=0$ means "the probability that no outcome occurs is 0."  Remember that the empty set is a _set_, not an _outcome_. Your last sentence about power sets seems unrelated to your question (but indeed the power set of a set is typically defined to include the empty set).

Comment: The set $\varnothing$ corresponds to "the impossible event".  It is assigned probability $0$.  Similarly $\Omega$ corresponds to "the certain event".  It is assigned probability $1$.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a consequence of the axioms of a probability measure: if $A$ is any event, then $A\cup\emptyset=A$ and $A\cap\emptyset=\emptyset$, hence
$$ \mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(A\cup\emptyset)=\mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(\emptyset)$$
Therefore we must have $\mathbb{P}(\emptyset)=0$.

Comment: Just to be complete, you must first derive finite additivity from countable additivity. This follows from the axiom that ℙ(∅) = 1 and countable additivity.

Comment: This is late, but I think you meant $P(S)$ in the above.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you pick a number between $1$ and $10$ at random. What's the probability that the number is even? $1/2$. What's the probability that you picked $1$ or $2$? $1/5$. Now, what's the probability that the number you picked is neither even nor odd?

Answer (score 5):

I think a more rigorous proof than previously given as answers uses more axioms of a probability measure. Of the three axioms, we need:

1. $\mathrm{P}(\Omega)=1$.
2. Given $A_i$ are mutually disjoint events in a sample space $\Omega$, $\mathrm{P}\left(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\right)= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathrm{P}(A_i)$

So we say $A_i = \emptyset$, because these are mutually disjoint, we can use axiom 2, such that:

$$\mathrm{P}\left(\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathrm{P}(A_i)=\mathrm{P}(\emptyset)+P(\emptyset)+\dotsb.$$

However, we know from axiom one that the probability of a event must be finite from axiom 1. Therefore $\mathrm{P}(\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i)<\infty$ is true only if $\mathrm{P}\left(\emptyset\right)=0$.

Comment: What I find a little odd by this proof (which is also located in Shreve's -
Stochastic Calculus for Finance II) is that by setting all $A_{i} = \emptyset$, $\forall i \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, one is performing the proof on an experiment where outcomes are $\emptyset$. However, don't we want to ensure that for *all* experiments $\mathcal{P}(\emptyset) = 0$?